# Why null exception in delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I am new delegates and event so i tried below code
but i got NullReference exception

```
public class Class1
{
    public delegate void load();

    static void Man( )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Man");

    }

    static void Dog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog");

    }

    load sas = new load(Man);


    public event load even;

    void Display()
    {
        even();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Class1 ss = new Class1();
        ss.Display();

    }
}
```

where i made error ....
thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event variables need to be assigned as well, before you could start calling them.

Your `event` variable called `even` has not been assigned, so it remains `null`. You need to assign it somewhere - for example, in your `Main` method:

```
static void Main()
{
    Class1 ss = new Class1();
    ss.even += Man;
    ss.Display();
}
```

Your `sas` variable, on the other hand, is assigned, but it remains unused. You can remove its declaration from the program.

[Here is a demo of your corrected programs running](http://ideone.com/HzLMUc).

Event processing code that goes to production needs to `null`-check events before making a call:

```
void Display()
{
    if (even != null) even();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you...how to assign event value in non-static method ?

Comment: @Happy If the method is non-static, you need to provide an object reference. For example, if you make `Man` and `Dog` non-static, you would need to use the `ss.even += ss.Dog` syntax ([demo](http://ideone.com/OO48xV)).